# CSS or jQuery to position divs at the bottom of the viewport

Tags: jquery, css

Please assist me fixing the two cartoon characters at the bottom of the content

CSS WORKS NOW: - Fixed position bottom as suggested: http://plungjan.name/test4.html

---

jQuery: http://plungjan.name/test2.html

Seems I am not correctly calculating where they should be.

Alternatively a pure CSS suggestion would be great since I in this case only use jQuery for that single thing of positioning.

Please note there are TWO of them, so I do not think I can use the footer glue or footerpush or whatever it is called .

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

     var footerHeight = 0,
         docHeight,
         footerTop = 0,
         $footer = $(".child");

     positionFooter();

     function positionFooter() {

       footerHeight = $footer.height();
       footerTop = ($("#contentcontainer").height()-footerHeight-45)+"px";
/*
      docHeight=$(document).height();
       if (footerTop > (docHeight-footerHeight)) {
         alert("using "+docHeight +" instead of "+footerTop)
         footerTop = (docHeight-footerHeight)+"px";
       } */

       $footer.animate({top: footerTop})
     }
     // $(window).scroll(positionFooter).resize(positionFooter)
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use

```
#boy1, #girl1 {
    bottom: 0
}
```

instead?

**Update**, more specifically: first go to your `global_styles.css` file. The one is used at http://plungjan.name/test2.html. Replace

```
#girl1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -95px;
    top: 170px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

with

```
#girl1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -95px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and

```
#boy1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 885px;
    top: 175px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

with

```
#boy1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 885px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Don't apply `position: fixed`.

Comment: And this is supported by what browsers?

Comment: @mplungjan Well, I didn't test, however absolute positioning had not had any incompatibilities across browsers.

Comment: getting a tiny scrollbar in IE8 to the extreme right.bottom:10px fixed that

Answer (score 1):

```
#boy1, #girl1 {bottom:0px;}
```

would do it.

Btw. you should place #girl1 outside the #hp_col_1 div, just like #boy1.